# OPT3001 - Read before Conversion in complete

Tags: sensor, light

What will happen if Light Sensor - OPT3001 conversion time field is set to 800ms but read request is set every 100ms. Unable to find/locate the info in Datasheet.
Additions Info:
Transparent hystersis comparison &  Continous Conversion is set.

Answer (score 0):

Section 7.6.1.1.1 (Result Register) of the datasheet says:

> This register contains the result of the most recent light to digital conversion.

The most recent conversion might be up to 800 ms old.

Answer (score 0):

The CRF bit in the Configuration Register indicates when a conversion is complete. If you're not using interrupts, you would poll this bit until it is set, then read the result, clear this bit and resume polling.